# Simplify declarations of classes that use the CRTP pattern

Tags: c++, templates, declaration, crtp

I used the ["Curiously Recurring Template Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to inherit a static member variable and an instance getter. Sounds contrived, but the project will have many many subclasses that need to be declared as painlessly as possible, without duplicating the code.

I came up with the following, which works just fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Base {
  virtual void printStrings() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct static_strings: Base {
  static std::vector<std::string> strings;

  static void addString(const std::string& s) {
    strings.push_back(s);
  }

  virtual void printStrings() {
    for (auto s: T::strings) {
      std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
  }
};

template <typename T> std::vector<std::string> static_strings<T>::strings;

struct Sub1: static_strings<Sub1> {};
struct Sub2: static_strings<Sub2> {};

int main() {
  Sub1::addString("test 1");
  std::shared_ptr<Base> s1 = std::make_shared<Sub1>();
  Sub2::addString("test 2");
  std::shared_ptr<Base> s2 = std::make_shared<Sub2>();
  std::cout << "s1: ";
  s1->printStrings();
  std::cout << "s2: ";
  s2->printStrings();
  return 0;
}
```

However, I'd like to further simplify the declaration of new subclasses, since right now I would have to copy the declaration and change the class name twice in the pasted line (`struct Sub3: static_strings<Sub3> {};`). I could use a macro, but I wonder if there's a non-macro (template?) way to do this?

Comment: `template<typename T> struct BaseWithStaticStrings : Base<T>, static_strings<T> {};` ?

Comment: @user253751 that would still require to write `struct X : BaseWithStaticStrings<X> {}`

Comment: For the update, you can separate your base into a templated and untemplated part. `typename<class T> struct Base2 : Base1`

Answer (score 1):

You could easily change your `Base` tp take a pack of template template arguments to derive from:

```
template <typename T, template<typename> typename... OtherBases>
struct Base : OtherBases<T>... {
  [...]
};

struct Sub1: Base<Sub1, static_strings> {};
struct Sub2: Base<Sub2, static_strings> {};
```

Not a big win here, but if you have more crtp base classes, that could help a bit. I can't imagine a way to save the remaining repetition without a macro, though.

Live code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/LquryX).

For the shared_pointer thing, you'll need to derive from an additional non-templated base class.

```
struct AbstractBase {
    virtual ~AbstractBase() = default;
    virtual void printStrings() = 0;
};

template <typename T, template<typename> typename... OtherBases>
struct Base : AbstractBase, OtherBases<T>... {... };
```

Then you create shared pointers from that one:

```
std::shared_ptr<AbstractBase> s1 = std::make_shared<Sub1>();
std::shared_ptr<AbstractBase> s2 = std::make_shared<Sub2>();
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jZQSve) for an updated example.

Comment: Down to one repetition ;) Guess I will write a macro then. Please also see my update above...

Comment: And while you were editing, I figured that part out by myself.. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper type:

```
struct helper : foo<helper>, bar<helper> {};
```

This alone won't do it, because all types inheriting from it would share the same base classes. To avoid repeating the type name you can introduce a dummy template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct bar{};

template <int x>
struct helper : foo<helper<x>>, bar<helper<x>> {};

using Sub1 = helper<1>;
using Sub2 = helper<2>;
int main () {

}
```

Thats what you can do without macros. With macros you can use `__COUNTER__` (gcc has it, not sure about the others) to get distinct `int`s:

```
using SubA = helper<__COUNTER__>;
using SubB = helper<__COUNTER__>;
```

Comment: You trade "repetition" with "generation" of unique id...

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice trick to remember. However, my code is just a toy example of what I'm doing, to make things easier. The subclasses will not be numerically labeled, I was just uncreative with my naming ;)

Comment: However, I *think* I see something else in your answer that I can use...

Comment: @Crazor there is no need to name the subclasses `Sub1`,`Sub2` etc, their names can be anything. The `int` parameter is just a dummy to have distinct instantiations of `helper`

Comment: @Jarod42 yes I know, I am not quite happy with it either. I was too enthusiastic and then hit a wall, so I posted at least this. I would perhaps just write `struct Sub1 : Base<Sub1> {};` and not worry about the repetition

Comment: You answer OP's question ;) I would also use CRTP normally so with "repetition" which seem better/simpler.